# How to copy column with the pandas and change the name?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 3 and Pandas I have this dataframe:

```
te.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5541 entries, 0 to 5664
Data columns (total 13 columns):
DATA_LS               4118 non-null object
DATA_INCLUS           2957 non-null object
Proprietario          5541 non-null object
Nome_propriedade      5541 non-null object
Municipio             5525 non-null object
Estado                5533 non-null object
CNPJ_CPF_CEI          5541 non-null object
CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo    5541 non-null float64
Trab_Envolv           4529 non-null float64
Ramo_atividade        2840 non-null object
Localizacao           2734 non-null object
Cod_ativ              2975 non-null object
Tipo_lista            5541 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 606.0+ KB
```

Please, how can I create a new column in this dataframe with a copy of column "CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo"? With the same lines and data, but another name, such as "New_column_tests"

Comment: `te['New_column_tests'] = te['CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inorder to add new column in the dataframe with the existing column data from same or different dataframe :

```
Dataframe_name['new_column_name'] = Dataframe_name['existing_column_name']
```

Comment: This won't create a shallow copy, right? I mean, 'new_column_name' will be a totally new, independent column, where I can change its values and it won't affect 'existing_column_name', right?